# this.value gives undefined in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am learning angular 5 ,I have copied this example from angular's official site.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
selector : "parent-onchange",
template :`
<br>
from parent componenet
<button value="minor" (click)="updateMin()">Minor</button>
<button value="major" (click)="updateMaj()">Major</button>
<child-onchange [major]="sendMaj" [minor]="sendMin"></child-onchange>`
})

export class ParentCompOnChange{
sendMaj : 1;
sendMin : 23;

updateMin(){
console.log("before"+this.sendMin);
this.sendMin++;
console.log(this.sendMin);
}

updateMaj(){
this.sendMaj++;
console.log(this.sendMaj);
}
}
```

So this line `console.log("before"+this.sendMin);` gives undefined value of sendMin and other console.logs give NAN (adding one to undefined).
Could anyone tell me what is wrong as per the official document [Angular 5](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) it should work fine.

Comment: `variableName:something` indicates `variableName` of type `something`. use `=` for assignment. (I see Sajeetharan pointed the same out in answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values with **`=`** not with **`:`**

```
sendMaj = 1;
sendMin = 23;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake:

```
sendMaj: 1 // < --- you create type 1
sendMin: 23 //< --- you create type 23
```

The solution is to create like this:

```
sendMaj: number = 1; // now you create sendMaj type number, value 1
sendMin: number = 23; // now you create sendMin type number, value 23
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public sendMaj = 1;
public sendMin = 23;
```